# How to get IFormFile / FormFile object in asp.et core

Tags: asp.net-core

Using ASP.NET core 2.1, have HttpRequest.Body with the uploaded file as MemoryStream. In the docs it says if I use asp.net core webAPI then can get that file as FormFile object. In my case I'm not using ASP.NET webAPI. Is there a way to get the FormFile object ? All I want to know the metadata of the file , like the filename, type etc. Once its in the memorystream I couldnt get that details easily.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 2):

ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  [Display(Name = "My File")]
  public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model MyViewModel
<form asp-action="Send" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label asp-for="File">Filename:</label>
   <input accept="image/*" title="Choose an image to upload" type="file"  asp-for="File" />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Send([Bind("File")] MyViewModel myVM)
{
   if (myVM.File?.Length > 0)
   {
        byte[] fileBytes;
        using (var fileStream = myVM.File.OpenReadStream())
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            fileStream.CopyTo(ms);
            fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
        }

        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(myVM.File.FileName);
        var fileMimeType = myVM.File.ContentType;
        var fileContent = fileBytes;

        //You have all the file attributes and content
   }
}
```